# install failed flex builder in eclipse in mars

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash-builder

i cannot download flash builder in eclipse. why?.  I am using eclipse mars for these purpose any one help me out to come from this problem it so important for me.

Comment: you can explain more than that, for exemple you can put screenshot, or picture of your problem

Comment: Flash builder is not compatible with Eclipse Mars.  You'll have to use Helios (3.6) or Indigo (3.7)

Answer (score 1):

The eclipse plugin for Flashbuilder claims to support 3.6 and later but this is false. In practise it works on 3.7 and not later.

People mentioned a workaround to get it to "work" on later versions:

Install Flashbuilder plugin on 3.7 and after that copy the dropins folder to the desired eclipse installation. You'll run into a few problems on first start but it is claimed to work generally ok after that.

But the safest bet is to use eclipse 3.7